# Newbie VBA: "Object required" error in "Sumif" command

Tags: vba, object, required

Pretty much new to VBA. Looking to do a simple SumIF from Excel, but having trouble with 424 errors, "Object Required".

My simple code is the following:

```
Sub Example1()

Dim TestVar As Long
Set TestVar = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf( _
                Arg1:=Sheet1.Range("B2:B11"), _
                Arg2:="1", _
                Arg3:=Sheet1.Range("A2:A11"))

End Sub
```

Hope any one can point out the mistake here.

Best,

ID

Follow-up question:

```
For i = 1 To 10

Range("G" & i + 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs( _
            Arg1:=Ark1.Range("A2:A11") And Ark1.Range("B2:B11"), _
            Arg2:=Range("A" & i + 1) And "a", _
            Arg3:=Ark1.Range("C2:C11"))

Next i
```

I get the following error message: Run-time error 13. Type Mismatch

Comment: It is your Set statement that provokes the error correct?

Comment: No tried without first, and gave the same mistake. Should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long is a considered a Data Type in VBA so you will need to make the code like the following:

```
Sub Example1()

Dim TestVar As Long
TestVar = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf( _
                Arg1:=Sheet1.Range("B2:B11"), _
                Arg2:="1", _
                Arg3:=Sheet1.Range("A2:A11"))

End Sub
```

Note that I removed the Set

Edit!

As requested here is an example of how you can set it up as a method where you parse in a value for Arg2.

```
Sub SumArea(ArgTwo As String, ArgTwo2 As String)
    Dim ToSum As Long
    ToSum = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Arg1:=Sheet1.Range("B2:B11"), Arg2:=ArgTwo AND ArgTwo2, Arg3:=Sheet1.Range("A2:A11"))
End Sub

Sub ThisMethodCallThem()

    SumArea ("1")

    SumArea ("2")


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I realized the problem now.

Comment: One more thing, and I will mark it closed (I will anyway of course); do you know how I add an extra argument in Arg2. That is, if it has to be 1 on some coloumn and 2 in another

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate it!

Comment: Hey McBoman. Partly.
What I hoped for was that there are two different arguments. So that the criteria was the the corresponding B-coloumn cell should be equal to 1 and the corresponding A-cell should be equal to "a" (simply as an example). Essentially what corresponds to a SumIFS

Comment: @pkpkPPkafa Maybe the new update works. Im not sure.

Comment: See at the orginal question, where I have posted the new code as well as the error msg.